# How to get fixed video size using Media Recorder android on two different devices?

Tags: android, android-camera, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I am trying to read more about media recorder. The Video size is coming out to be different in different devices. In one device video size was around 31 MB and in other it was 88.5 MB.

Below is the code, that I am used for the media recorder.

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);
recorder.setVideoSize(optimalVideoSize.width, optimalVideoSize.height);
recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1000000);
recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
recorder.setMaxDuration(time_limit*1000);
```

where, optimalvideosize is an arraylist outputted using the below function:

```
private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) 
{
final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.2;
double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
if (sizes == null)
    return null;

Size optimalSize = null;
double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

int targetHeight = h;

// Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
for (Size size : sizes) 
{
    Log.d("Camera", "Checking size " + size.width + "w " + size.height
            + "h");
    double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
    if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
        continue;
    if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) 
    {
        optimalSize = size;
        minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
    }
}

// Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the
// requirement
if (optimalSize == null) 
{
    minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for (Size size : sizes) 
    {
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) 
        {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }
}
return optimalSize;
}
```

Thanks for the Help!!

Comment: "The Video size is coming out to be different in different devices. In one device video size was around 31 MB and in other it was 88.5 MB" -- that is perfectly normal. Those videos are probably taken at different resolutions or may use somewhat different encoding options. They might even be of different scenes, have different audio, etc.

Comment: What is the output of the Log.d line? That is, what recording size are you using in the end on these different devices?